# How to Search Inside Html Code for Specific Class in R?

Tags: html, r, xml, html-parsing, rvest

Are there any good way in R that I can check if the class exist in bigger class or not; Lets say my Html code looks something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="Parent class">
    <span class="Children one"></span>
    <span class="Children two"></span>
    <span class="Children three"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="Parent class">
    <span class="Children two"></span>
    <span class="Children three"></span>
    <span class="Children four "></span>
  </div>

  <div class="Parent class">
    <span class="Children three"></span>
    <span class="Children one"></span>
    <span class="Children six "></span>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I want to know  if  the class "Children one" does exist in "Parent class" or no; So my final results will be something like this or anything can indicate the existence or the absence of the class page.

```
which(Parent class %in%  Children one)
[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Where `html` is a string, filepath, or URL of your HTML code,

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

html %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes('.Parent') %>% 
    map_lgl(~length(html_nodes(.x, '.one')) > 0)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, note that classes can't have spaces in them in HTML, or it gets counted as two classes; thus CSS selectors `.Parent`, but then `.one`. You could search for both classes each time with `.Parent.class` and `.Children.one`, if you like.